# Character encoding problem - I suppose (UTF-8 - JS and Windows1250 - PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, cp1250

all my problems so far I resolved by serching this forum, but now I reched to a wall.. :)  mayby the problem is I'm  don't know what question to ask..

So my problem is:
I have submiting form in witch user put tracking list number - and for some cases this number starts with "%000xxxx" character.
Using JS, and AJAX I make post to PHP endpoint. So fare, everything is ok, in console.log(data) I'm geting url:

```
endppoint/trackingNumber=%000xxxx&foo=bar
```

The problem starts in php (it's my guess)
In POST details, in request I have somthing like this:

```
trackingNumber: \u000xxx
foo: bar
```

and when I'm printing in PHP controler - I get:

```
 " 0xxx"
```

PHP - is old one,  5.3.3

Done:

```
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1',$data);
```

I'd like to be able to post via PHP full tracking number (with %000 instead of " 0") and understand that isue.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your root problem is that `%` is significant in URL encoding, with `%00` decoding to a null/zero byte. So before you include data in a URL you should `urlencode()` it.

```php
$trackingNumber = "%000xxx";
$foo = "bar";

$url = 'endppoint/?trackingNumber=' . urlencode($trackingNumber) . '&foo=' . urlencode($foo);

parse_str(parse_url($url)['query'], $parsed); // how it will be read

var_dump(
    $url,
    $parsed
);
```

Output:

```
string(43) "endppoint/?trackingNumber=%25000xxx&foo=bar"
array(2) {
  ["trackingNumber"]=>
  string(7) "%000xxx"
  ["foo"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Additionally, though the encoding does not seem to be significant in this specific case, you need to be careful with your encoding choices. Windows cpXXXX encodings and ISO-8859-X encodings are *not* equivalent, and should not be interchanged. PHP can convert either type of encoding if necessary, eg:

```php
iconv('UTF-8', 'cp1250', $data);
iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-2', $data); // cp1250's rough equivalent in 8859, illustrative only
```

Also 1250 itself is seldom used, so unless you're working on a legacy system in Eastern Europe it's probably not that. Maybe cp1252?

Lastly, just general advice, is that text encoding is *metadata* that should always be *known*, never guessed, and anything that claims to "detect" the encoding is also guessing.

See:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#Windows-125x_series
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#The_parts_of_ISO/IEC_8859

Comment: `urlencode($trackingNumber)` solved all my problems. Work like a charm :)
Cp1250 -  Eastern Europe, and system which is legacy for current legacy ;) 
Thank's.